# The tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$of $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Many resources defined $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ as all pairs $(l,z) \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ s.t. $z \in l$. What does it mean?

My guess is that it means that $z$ is in the span of $l$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$(l,z)\in\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ such that $z\in l$" ? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle for the real Grassmannian, which should be pretty similar. Then as $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the set of lines of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, it would make sense

Comment: right, sorry about that. $l$ does not include the origin, so I am not sure whether it is accurate to say that $z \in l$.

Comment: If you take $\mathbb P^n$ to be the lines in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, $l$ does contain the origin, so it is accurate

Comment: So if I use the formal definition of $\mathbb{P}^n$ as $\mathbb {C}^{n+1}-\{0\}/\mathbb C^{\ast}$. Does it make sense to say that the definition is equivalent to $z \in \langle l \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, this works equally well (note that there *is* a formal definition with lines)